# What happens to interprocess memory if one of the processes dies unexpectedly?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-memory

if you are interested in motivation Ill elaborate it in next few sentences, if not just skip to the Q.

I was thinking about making fast logger but the one that is not affected when program crashes(aka few last log msgs arent lost). So my idea is to write to the shared memory(ringbuffer) and have another low prio process read from it and do the dumping.
But for that to work I need to know what happens to shared memory if one process exits(normal exit, SEGFAULT)...

So my question is:
What happens to shared memory (in Linux, but you can answer for Win also) when one of the procs die? Is it UB?

Comment: Since writing to shared memory actually ends up in writing to a file, what's the benefit to do this indirectly by shared memory and separate process instead of writing directly to log-file w/o buffering?

Comment: for example I can(I think :) ) write & read GBs of data to 1MB shared mem...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What happens to shared memory (in Linux, but you can A for Win also) when one of the procs die?

Nothing. When a process dies, the shared memory is left as it is. It is mapped as a file under `/dev/shm/` directory. It is removed either when the system reboots, or when all processes unmmap the shared memory file and the `shm_unlink()` is called.

> Is it UB?

No, it is well defined. See the [man page for shm_overview(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/shm_overview) :

> POSIX shared memory objects have kernel persistence: a shared memory object will exist until the system is shut down, or until all processes have unmapped the object and it has been deleted with shm_unlink(3)

Comment: cool, does cleanup(by OS) of a abruptly ended process reduces refcount to that shared memory, or is that permanent leak?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Opening a shared memory is the same as opening a file. When a process dies, the OS should clean up after it. I would say that happens, unless there is an OS bug (high unlikely)

Comment: @BЈовић doesn't your comment that "the OS should clean it up" contradict the man of shm_overview statement (cited in your answer above) that "a shared memory object will exist until the system is shut down, or until all processes have unmapped the object and it has been deleted with shm_unlink(3)" ? The kernel persistence does mean that the object will persist  until the kernel of the operating system reboots or it is is explicitly deleted, doesn't it?

Answer (score 4):

Read boost IPC mechanisms, they explain persistence concept about shared memory.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/interprocess/some_basic_explanations.html#interprocess.some_basic_explanations.persistence

Answer (score 1):

If you use a file as backing for [`mmap`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html), everything up to the last [`msync`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/msync.2.html), or `munmap` if the process exits properly, will be available to independent processes.

So, there should be no problem with the shared memory, when a process crashes.